# Abstract Common SQL Query To Method (Different Where Clause)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say you have a common query, something that you keep copy and pasting over and over again in SQL. Let's assume for simplicity sake something like this, that just returns the total records and the records that match there WHERE condition.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TheseMatch, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) ThisIsMyTotal
FROM [MyTable]  
WHERE MyCondition = 'MyCondition'
```

Through the rest of your script, the only thing that is changing is the WHERE clause. So your next query might be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TheseMatch, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) ThisIsMyTotal
FROM [MyTable]  
WHERE MyCondition = 'MyCondition' OR MyCondition = 'MyCondition1'
```

Between the two, there is much commonality, and the only difference really is the WHERE. Is there a way in SQL to abstract the top three lines to a static method that can be commonly called in an effort to introduce some level of reuse, perhaps passing in the WHERE as a parameter?

TIA!

Comment: Passing the where clause is not a good idea. That forces you to use dynamic sql and then you have to deal with sql injection. You could use table valued parameters and just do an inner join to your parameter on MyCondition. You should never keep copying and pasting code in any language. That is a clear sign something needs to thought about differently as it creates debugging and maintenance nightmares.

Comment: @SeanLange if you flesh out the table-valued parameter method as an answer, I'll upvote it. There's a couple other ways to do it too, but that's probably one of the cleanest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a table valued parameter here because you have to support multiple conditions. Basically you will need to define your table type and then you can treat it just like any other table inside your stored proc.

You can read more details and implementation syntax here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx